# Android country-based App not showing on Google search

Tags: android, google-play, google-search

I've uploaded an Android App only available to four countries. I can't see its Google Play link indexed on Google search results. At first I thought it was due to it not being available in my country but running some tests I've found links to Apps not available at all in my country (for example ABC live TV) and whose results appear in Google Search results. Is there anything I must do to help Google index my App? I've seen there's a framework called Google Indexing but as far as I've read it's more focused on deep-linking rather than app discovery.

Just to clarify, I can access the App via the direct link from Google Play if I click on it on my Google Play Developer Console but I can't see my App in the search results if I look for it.

Can anyone just share some light about this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be just waiting for a couple weeks to wait for Google to index the App, now it's appearing properly